# Find base of isosceles triangle with side length and angle

Tags: trigonometry

I would like to calculate the length of the side in red on the image.
I tried the [Law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), but maybe i haven't applied the formula right, because for a side "a" and "b" of size 64 and a angle of 120, the result is 39.

How to calculate the right length of c for the image?

[image]

Comment: It would be useful if you could list all the steps you took in order for us to help you spot where you may have gone wrong.

Comment: I believe your mistake must have been that you calculated $\cos(120)$ using **radians** instead of **degrees**.

Comment: @David, I have updated the image to the real measures! Please, share the ways.

Comment: @Mufasa, yes! I tried it with radians and the result is the espected! Thanks! I used this formula: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/5/f/b/5fb96ece636c260714618844e32210db.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can bisect your angle given ($120$ degrees) to $60$ degrees.
Then you will notice that you will have formed two triangles that follow the $30$-$60$-$90$ triangle format. $64$ is your hypotenuse and the triangle side you're looking for is $64\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 3):

In an isosceles triangle as shown, the bisector of the $120^\circ$ angle is the perpendicular bisector of the base.  So
$$\frac c2=b\sin60^\circ\ .$$

Answer (score 3):

Split the triangle in two right triangles whose lower or base side is $\frac{c}{2}.\;$ Now these "new triangles" have angles, $60^\circ$, $30^\circ$ and $90^\circ$, respectively.

As $\cos(30^\circ) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $, now you can easily check that $\frac{c}{2} = \frac{64 \cdot \sqrt{3}}{2} = 32 \cdot \sqrt{3}$. So $c = 64 \cdot \sqrt{3}$.

As for the other side, you must do the same thing but with sine. $\sin(30^\circ) = \frac{1}{2}$, so the height of the triangle is $32$.

Comment: Note that the legs of the triangle have length $64$ rather than $32$.  Also, you solved for $c/2$ rather than $c$.

Comment: Oops, sorry, corrected it.